# How to continue to use expired GPG keys (but still verify signatures)?

Tags: apt

So MongoDB 4.0 key has expired ([forum post](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-4-0-release-signing-key-is-a-badsig/1784), [forum post](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-4-0-debian-gpg-key-expired-few-days-ago/224006)). I know that I can make it so that apt does not validate signatures (with `--allow-unauthenticated` or `--allow-insecure-repositories` flag), but I would not like to completely ignore signatures, I would like that the signature is still checked, only that expiration of the key is ignored. The key has not been compromised, so signatures are still secure (and prevent somebody from injecting something bad). Is it possible to just ignore the expiration?

Comment: You can not have both, Ignore security and have security.

Comment: I want to ignore expiration of the key, but verify cryptographically that the signature still matches the key.